# various definitions of abstraction layers

Tags: abstraction, platform

I see there are different definition of abstraction layers used in software engineering, OSAL (OS abstraction layer), PAl (platform abstraction) and SAL (system abstraction). I understand that OSAL deals mainly with OS specifics, such mutexes, memory allocation etc. but I don't see how PAL/SAL are different? Or these are just different names for the same thing?

My current understanding is that PAL traditionally/historically deals with platform, i.e. hardware, wand attempts to encapsulate CPU specific features, while SAL (aka OSAL?) deals with higher level, which is operating system and attempts to abstract OS calls etc.

I will appreciate any feedback and comments.

Thanks.